# How retrieve a JSON object in a GSP view from a controller

Tags: json, grails, gsp

The controller has the next method (I'm recycling my implementation of the [bootstrap-file-upload plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/bootstrap-file-upload)):

```
def uploadImage() {     
    String baseName;
    String imageExtension = uploadPhotoService.imagesExtension;
    String thumbnailExtension = uploadPhotoService.thumbnailsExtension;

    switch(request.method){
        case "GET":

            def results = []    
            String imagesDirectoryPath = uploadPhotoService.getImageDirectoryDestinationPath(params.idAlojamiento);
            def dir = new File(imagesDirectoryPath)

            if( dir.exists() ) {
                dir.eachFile { 
                    baseName = uploadPhotoService.removeFileExtension(it.getName());

                    results << [
                            name: baseName,
                            size: it.length(),
                            url: createLink(controller:'alojamiento', action:'picture', params:[imageName: baseName + "." + imageExtension, idAlojamiento: params.idAlojamiento]),
                            thumbnail_url: createLink(controller:'alojamiento', action:'thumbnail', params:[imageName: baseName + "." + thumbnailExtension, idAlojamiento: params.idAlojamiento]),
                            delete_url: createLink(controller:'alojamiento', action:'deleteImage', params:[baseName: baseName, idAlojamiento: params.idAlojamiento]),
                            delete_type: "DELETE"
                    ]
                }
            }               
            render results as JSON
            break;
        case "POST":
            (...)
```

In the view, there is the next line:

```
<g:include controller="alojamiento" action="uploadImage" params="[idAlojamiento:alojamientoInstance.id]"/>
```

So the Internet browser shows a text line with the content of the JSON results variable:

```
[{"name":"boceto escaleras patio","size":37567,"url":"/AlojamientoPrototipo/alojamiento/picture?imageName=boceto+escaleras+patio.jpg&idAlojamiento=1","thumbnail_url":"/AlojamientoPrototipo/alojamiento/thumbnail?imageName=boceto+escaleras+patio.png&idAlojamiento=1","delete_url":"/AlojamientoPrototipo/alojamiento/deleteImage?baseName=boceto+escaleras+patio&idAlojamiento=1","delete_type":"DELETE"},
(...)
```

I don't want to show that text line. I want to loop through all images. I think it could work:

```
<g:each in="${results}">
    <img src="${it.thumbnail_url}"/>
</g:each>
```

How could I to pass the results JSON variable to the GSP view to loop through it?

Comment: The plugin docs says to use `<bsfu:fileUpload action="upload" controller="image"/>`. Why are you using `g:include` instead?

Comment: I'm using `<bsfu:fileUpload action="upload" controller="image"/>` to upload the images. But my idea is to use the same controller  to show the images in a twitter bootstrap carousel. That's why I'm also using `g:include` in another view.

Comment: Why don't you just create another action to display the images? Then you don't need to send them as JSON...

Comment: Yes, I would repeat some code, but I would be simpler to understand. Probably is the best solution!

Comment: To not repeat yourself, you can create a Service and use it in your controllers :-)

Comment: I'm completely agree :)

Answer (score 3):

To get a variable like that:

```
<g:set var="results" value="${g.include(controller: "alojamiento", action: "uploadImage", params: [idAlojamiento:alojamientoInstance.id])}" />  
<g:each in="${JSON.parse(results)}">
    <img src="${it.thumbnail_url}"/>
</g:each>
```

However I should mention that you should just send this down the initial call. Put the logic in a service to make it reusable.

Edit: Forgot it was a string

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand what you mean with "However I should mention that you should just send this down the initial call". Do you mean I can use it just once per view?

Comment: It does not work. The error shown is: `No such property: thumbnail_url for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer`. Performing different tests, I observed that `it` has the whole `results` variable. `it` is: `[{"name":"boceto escaleras (...) elete_type":"DELETE"},{"name":"focona la linea de la concepc (...)`

Comment: Whatever model you pass down initially to the gsp (ie whatever action renders the view), you should include this data

Comment: OK. But the loop doesn't work properly. I guess I should refactorize the code (moving more data to a service) to make it reusable both for the [bootstrap-file-upload plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/bootstrap-file-upload) and the code I posted here

Comment: I moved the code to a service, but still isn't working. I posted the new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598486/how-to-pass-a-list-of-maps-to-a-gsp-page-view-and-iterate-over-it) (I didn't post the service to simplify the question)