# How to pass a List of Maps to a GSP page view and iterate over it

Tags: loops, grails, groovy, gsp

Let's say we want to show information about the files of a folder. We have to save the information of each file in a Map. Then, add these Maps to a List.

Controller action:

```
def show() {

    List results = new ArrayList();

    File dir = getDir(params.id);

    if (dir.exists()) {
        dir.eachFile { 

        Map fileInformation= new java.util.LinkedHashMap()

        fileInformation.put("name", it.getName());
        fileInformation.put("size", it.length());
        fileInformation.put("path", it.getAbsolutePath() );

        results.add(fileInformation);

        }
    }

    [filesOfFolderData: result]
}
```

Maybe, this is my best attempt to get the data in the view (I followed the approach of [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/iterate-over-arraylist-in-gsp-help-td1332640.html) with no luck):

```
<g:each in="${filesOfFolderData}">

    <p> it: ${it}</p>
    <p> it.properties: ${it.properties} </p>

    <g:each var="propertyEntry" in="${it.properties}">

        <p> propertyEntry.key: ${propertyEntry.key} </p>
        <p> propertyEntry.value: ${propertyEntry.value} </p>
        <p> propertyEntry.value.name: ${propertyEntry.value} </p>           

    </g:each>

</g:each>
```

This is what the Internet Browser shows (note: the first line of the result could be a little bit different as I simplify the code so I guest that result in base of the real result of my case):

```
it: [{name=wololo1, size=35, path=c:\}, {name=wololo2, size=35, path=c:\}]

it.properties: {class=class java.util.ArrayList, empty=false}

propertyEntry.key: class

propertyEntry.value: class java.util.ArrayList

propertyEntry.value.name: class java.util.ArrayList

propertyEntry.key: empty

propertyEntry.value: false

propertyEntry.value.name: false
```

How could we iterate over the List?

Answer (score 2):

With `each` in maps you have access to the `key` and `value`, so just iterate over the value.

```
<g:each in="${filesOfFolderData}" var="files">
  <g:each in="${files.value}" var="file">
    ...
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

Comment: It works but ONLY if we construct a Map of Maps (and not a List of Maps). I'll answer my own question as it is recommended in [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194463/why-was-my-edit-with-the-intention-to-complete-an-answer-rejected). Thanks for your help one more time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the code given below:
Example:

```
filesOfFolderData= [{name=wololo1, size=35, path=c:\}, {name=wololo2, size=35, path=c:\}]

<g:each in="${filesOfFolderData}" var="fileMap">
  <g:each in="${fileMap}" var="file">
    ${file.key}: ${file.value}
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

Output:

```
name: wololo1
size: 35
path: c:\
name: wololo2
size:35
path: c:\
```

Hope that helps!!!

Thanks

Comment: This is List of map as you can see in the example given above...that is what you require.

Comment: Thanks man, but If I wrote that, I got the compiler error: `Groovy:unexpected char: '\' @ line 95, column 66.` I changed it to: `def filesOfFolderData= [{url="wololo1", thumbnail_url="35", name="c:\\"} {url="wololo2", thumbnail_url="35", name="c:\\"}]`. But it gives a compiler error at the first comma: `Groovy:expecting '}', found ',' @ line 94, column 41.` I tried without commas and another compiler error...

Comment: Ah! Use the same code in the controller as you have mentioned in your question and use code given below in the gsp :                                <g:each in="${filesOfFolderData}" var="fileMap">
  <g:each in="${fileMap}" var="file">
    ${file.key}: ${file.value}
  </g:each>
</g:each>

Comment: It won't work. We have to use a Map of Maps instead of a List of Maps. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of a List of Maps, we have to create a Map of Maps**:

```
def show() {

    def results = []
    File dir = getDir(params.id);

    if (dir.exists()) {
        dir.eachFile {  

            results <<  [
                            name: it.getName(),
                            size: it.length(),
                            it.getAbsolutePath()
                        ]                   
        }
    }

    [filesOfFolderData: result]
}
```

Then, the solution of @SergioMichels will work perfectly (I copy&paste his solution):

```
<g:each in="${filesOfFolderData}" var="files">
  <g:each in="${files.value}" var="file">
    ...
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

Comment: But, [fileOfFolderData:results] is passed as model to view so on view if you access fileOfFolderData is List of Maps. Here, you are sending [{name=wololo1, size=35, path=c:\}, {name=wololo2, size=35, path=c:\}]  which is the value of fileOfFolderData isn't it?

Comment: [name: it.getName(),size: it.length(),path: it.getAbsolutePath()] should be used which is a correct map.

Comment: I know it is strange, but it is how Grails works. Grails wants that you pass a Map to the view, not a List, so we have to fake it. In this example, the "parent Map" has only one key (filesOfFolderData) and one value (results, which contains all the Maps).